# RAILS: How to make new collection.build in a callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, callback

How to create a new record in after_save using other model?

I tried this line which resulted "undefined method `journals' for nil:NilClass"

e.g.

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
  resources :journals
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :profile
  has_many :journals
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :create_new_journal_if_none

  private
    def create_new_journal_if_none
      if user.journals.empty? ????
        user.journals.build() ????
      end
    end
end

class Journals < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user
end
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? Create a new journal once user's profile has been created?

Comment: Yes i need to create journal (user.journals) automatically after user's profile is created

Comment: your code seems valid, but check that appropriate tables and created and rails code reloaded.

Comment: It's also possible that the new profile being created isn't being assigned to the user properly .. hence the nil:NilClass error

Answer (score 1):

Nested models are going to be saved as well once parent saves, so it's easy to use before_create block and build a nested resource here.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  before_create do 
    user.journals.build unless user.journals.any?
  end
end
```

This line of code will create a profile and a journal assigned with the User

```
User.find(1).create_profile(name :test)
```

Comment: i get error msg: undefined method `journals' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @smileyUser can you show the code that you're using to test this out? It would help to see how you're creating the user and profile, since that could give some insight into why the user is nil.

Comment: @Ben this is an simplified version as an example code of my actual project which is too large.  I kept getting nil at the moment.  I am in attempt to create and to update using models callbacks only.  user.profile has been created successfully but I am unable to create new user.journals (via callback) as "undefined method `journals' for nil:NilClass" as resulted.

Comment: @smileyUser I highly recommend trying to get this example code working (with a test case) so that you can either determine a minimal failing example, or figure out what's different between your complex codebase and the small example.

Comment: @smileyUser copy-paste full stack trace with line number and corresponded lines of code please? The second, add **Rails.logger.error self.inspect** inside the before_create block, a bit more details please